# netlogo help for put more conditions

Tags: netlogo

I'm new, and I need to do something for my master, but I really don't have idea!!
I want to put a new characteristic in a breed.... like make a difference between people (who have more money and who have less) but I was trying everything and always i have a new problem.

What do you recommend to me? What do I need to put?

I have "compradores" but now I want to put a difference on them (and I don't know how) (in the space we have stores and list of shop).

```
ask patches [ set pcolor yellow ]
set productos ["aceite" "bebidas" "cerveza" "detergente" "especias" "flores" "gasoil" "huevos" "infusiones" "jamon" "kafe" "levadura"]
set-default-shape compradores "person"
create-compradores 10 [
  set color pink set heading 0 set size 2
  setxy (random world-width) + min-pxcor (random world-height) + min-pycor
  set lista-de-compra n-values 10 [item (random (length productos)) productos]
  set memoria []
]
```

Comment: I am not really sure of what you exactly need to do with that “difference” but I assume you could use ```compradores-own [difference ]``` where ```difference``` is a variable belonging to agents of your breed. Then you can choose the value of that variable for your agents.

Comment: pol, thanks i have another question, can you help me?

Comment: i dont know how to put all the globals in the shopping (and not only one) 
  set-default-shape tiendas "circle"
 create-shoppings 1
 [
 set color white set heading 0 set size 6
 setxy (random world-width) + min-pxcor
 (random world-height) + min-pycor
 set locales item  locales-numero productos
    set label locales set label-color red
 ]

Comment: As this is a different issue, it is more appropriate to ask a new question with that problem. All members from the community and I will be glad to help you with that!

Comment: Hi @ArcoluirisA., I suggest you take a look at the [ask], the [mre] and the [homework-related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) help pages to improve your question and make it more answerable. This will increase your chances of receiving support here